# Building app for Cydia with Apple Code Signing

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, cydia, codesign

For the first time, I want to build an app for Cydia Store. I have an Apple developer account and also a provision file for my app. I see on most tutorials about building apps for Cydia that say:

> "build your app by self code signing".

I need to know, if I build an app with an Apple developer code signature and valid provision file, is it possible that my app won't work correctly on jailbroken iPhones, or Cydia won't approve my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create your app using XCode and then make sure to not codesign

How to for bypassing xcode codesign: http://txcom2003.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/disable-code-signing-in-xcode-4/

You can then pseudo code sign using

```
ldid -S ExampleApplication
```

[Here's a how to for code signing.](http://www.saurik.com/id/8)

Then just 'build the application' from within xcode, you can then package it to a deb file using

```
dpkg -b ExampleApplication
```

and send the newly created deb file to modmyi.

You can also create your own server and host it yourself.

How to for cydia repo: http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/how-to-easy-make-a-cydia-repo.110310/

Comment: So thanks Omar for your reply, I've been made app by apple code sign and then created deb file with it. and sent it to Cydia. the current version is working on jailbroken devices!!!!